# How do I compress a PDF file in byte array format using NodeJS and React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, compression

How can I compress a PDF file in byte array format?
I have a NodeJS project using react, and I have an byte array that contains info of the PDF. This format is used un multiple functions, so i cant change it. I need to compress that PDF but i dont know how or if there is an axisting library for this case.

I have read about some libraries that can compress pdf files, but the work with a local pdf file instead an array of bytes like mine. I was looking for some ideas, because i have no idea of where to start